# Eclipse Plugin API: how can I add javadoc support for specific platform plugins?

Tags: api, eclipse-plugin, javadoc, jface

using Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede and I cannot find the way to add javadoc support for all platform plugin apis, but specifically to JFace e Ui Forms packages.

Opening the property panel of any jar linked to the library named "plug-in dependecies" I receive  the following message into the "Javadoc location"  node:

> The current class path entry belongs to container 'Plug-in Dependencies' 
>      wich does not allow user    modifications to Javadoc locations in its entries"...

what does it mean, that I must re-build Eclipse with some wired javadoc location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the eclipse SDK ["classic", "RCP/Plugin" or "Modeling"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) installed, that means sources for the eclipse plugins are included.

While it is true you cannot setup Javadoc for those plugins, you still access to that documentation since the sources are here, fully "Java-documented".

If there are no sources, you still can [import all eclipse plugins with their sources](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) in a dedicated workspace.

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/images/eclipsesource30.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/images/eclipsesource30.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse 3.4.2 with visual editor 1.4.0.
For some reason, my eclipse doesn't find the swt javadocs by default and the "import plugins method" does not work.
But I found a work arround:

Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar
add /plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.3.4.1.v3452b.jar

edit the "source attachment" to org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.source_3.4.1.v3452b.jar

Press ok. Note, that you are now using swt "twice" :O)

If it is still not working, go to the same dialog, remove the "Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)" and press ok. Return to the dialog and add it again with the button "Add Library" -> SWT -> IDE Platform. Press ok. Close all Visual Editors. And go to Project -> Clean...

Now you the Javadocs are displayed directly in Eclipse and Visual Editor still works.